# Nash equilibrium - mistake in proof of paper?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, public-economics, public-goods

I have a question regarding the proof of Proposition 1 in [Besley and Ghatak (2007)](http://personal.lse.ac.uk/ghatak/csr.pdf) in Appendix A of their paper. It is a quite highly cited paper but I believe there is a mistake in the proof of their Proposition 1. The model is described in Section 2. of their paper. It is a very simple model that seeks to derive the Nash equilibrium of the market. In particular, they show that $\theta_c^*$ must satisfy $f'(n \theta_c^*) = \alpha$ in equilibrium. In their proof in the appendix they state:

[image]

However, I think there is a mistake because the package $(p', \widehat{\theta'})$ does **not** make each caring consumer strictly better off.

The new package $(p', \widehat{\theta'})$ gives utility:

$$b-p'+f(\widehat{\theta'} + (n-1)\widehat{\theta}) $$

The old package $(p, \widehat{\theta})$ gives utility:

$$b-p+f(n\widehat{\theta}) $$

The new package is strictly preferred to the old package iff

$$b-p'+f(\widehat{\theta'} + (n-1)\widehat{\theta}) > b-p+f(n\widehat{\theta})$$

$$ f(n\widehat{\theta} + \Delta \widehat{\theta}) - f(n\widehat{\theta}) > \Delta p$$

If we make the substitution as stated in the paper: $\Delta p = f'(n\widehat{\theta}) \Delta \widehat{\theta}$ and assuming we want a positive $\Delta \widehat{\theta}$, then the above becomes:

$$\frac{f(n\widehat{\theta} + \Delta \widehat{\theta}) - f(n\widehat{\theta})}{\Delta \widehat{\theta}} > f'(n \widehat{\theta}) $$

If we pick a negative $\Delta \widehat{\theta}$, then the above condition becomes

$$\frac{f(n\widehat{\theta} + \Delta \widehat{\theta}) - f(n\widehat{\theta})}{\Delta \widehat{\theta}} < f'(n \widehat{\theta}) $$

But $f$ is a increasing and strictly concave function, so the above inequalities are always false. So the new package is **never** preferred to the old package. Everything else in the proof is fine apart from this step and this is the most crucial step of the proof as it characterizes what $\widehat{\theta}$ should be in equilibrium, if this is wrong then many other results in the paper are also wrong.

So, is there a mistake in this part of the proof of the paper? And if so, is there a way to correct it so that the results still hold?

Comment: I just skimmed the paper, so perhaps I missed something. But I noticed that your final inequality is different from theirs. While you're comparing with $f'(n\hat{\theta})$, they are comparing with $f'(n\hat{\theta}+ \Delta \hat{\theta})$. Isn't this the problem or I missed something?

Comment: Yes, the inequality would be correct if it's $f'(n\widehat{\theta}+\Delta\widehat{\theta})$ on the RHS, but in their paper, they define $\Delta p = f'(n\widehat{\theta}) \Delta \widehat{\theta}$. In particular, I am confused on page 1661 of the paper where I quote:

"We show that there exists a package of this form which will make each caring consumer strictly better off. The payoff of a caring consumer who accepts this package is $b-p'+f(\widehat{\theta'} + (n-1)\widehat{\theta})$"

But as I just showed above, the new package cannot be strictly preferred.

Comment: Also, on page 1661 of the paper, their final inequality is perfectly fine, I am not referring to that inequality as that is talking about a different part of the proof. I am referring to the section of the proof above that where they are comparing the "old" package $(p, \widehat{\theta})$ to the "new" package $(p', \widehat{\theta'})$. This is a crucial step of the proof since everything else relies on this result and I believe there is a mistake here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The objective is to show that, as long as $f'(n\hat\theta)\ne \alpha$, a firm can always engineer a package $(p',\hat\theta')=(p+\Delta p,\hat\theta+\Delta \hat{\theta})$ such that (i) a caring consumer strictly prefers this package, and (ii) the firm makes positive profits.

1) Your maths are correct: the inequalities are always false when f is increasing and strictly concave. In that case, the proof in the paper is unclear.
The package $(p',\hat\theta')=(p+f'(n\hat\theta)\Delta \hat{\theta},\hat\theta+\Delta \hat{\theta})$ does not satisfy (i).

2) You can show the proposition with the following reasoning.
Assume $f'(n\hat\theta)>\alpha$. Take any $h$ within the interval $(\alpha,f'(n\hat\theta))$.
For $\Delta \hat{\theta}$ small enough and positive, a firm that offers the package $(p',\hat\theta')=(p+h\Delta \hat{\theta},\hat\theta+\Delta \hat{\theta})$ satisfies (i) and (ii). With a first-order appoximation, we show (i): $$b-p'+f(\hat\theta'+(n-1)\hat\theta)>b-p+f(n \hat\theta),$$
and (ii):
$$\Delta p - \alpha \Delta \theta>0.$$

Assume $f'(n\hat\theta)<\alpha$, and take $h$ within the interval $(f'(n\hat\theta),\alpha)$.
For $\Delta \hat{\theta}$ small enough and **negative**, a firm that offers the package $(p',\hat\theta')=(p+h\Delta \hat{\theta},\hat\theta+\Delta \hat{\theta})$ satisfies (i) and (ii).

Comment: Thanks so much for looking into this! However, I believe your argument above is not quite right because if we pick $\Delta \widehat{\theta}<0$, then the correct condition should be $$\frac{f(n\hat\theta+\Delta\hat\theta)-f(n\hat\theta)}{\Delta\hat\theta}<f'(n\hat\theta)$$ More generally, the package $(p', \widehat{\theta'})$ is preferred to $(p, \widehat{\theta})$ iff $f(n\hat\theta+\Delta\hat\theta)-f(n\hat\theta) > \Delta p$. In your example, we have $\ln(1) - \ln(2) \approx -0.6931$ while $\Delta p = f'(n\hat\theta)\Delta \widehat{\theta} =-0.5$, so the new package is **not** preferred.

Comment: To avoid confusion, I have also just edited my original question to distinguish the cases when $\Delta \widehat{\theta}>0$ and $\Delta \widehat{\theta}<0$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Your arguments make absolute sense and fixes the proof!